# Galois extension and Same degree of all Irreducible Factors

Tags: galois-theory

Let $L$ be a Galois extension of $F$ and let $p(x) ∈ F[x]$ be irreducible. I wish to show that all irreducible factors of $p(x) ∈ L[x]$ have the same degree. Note that we do not assume that $p(x)$ has a root in $L$. By [Normal Extension Equivalent to Same Degree Irreducible Factors (Hungerford, Exercise V.3.24)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/248759/normal-extension-equivalent-to-same-degree-irreducible-factors-hungerford-exer)
I know an algebraic extension $F$ of $L$ is normal over $L$ if and only if for every irreducible $p\in L[x],p$ factors in $F[x]$ as a product of irreducible factors which have the same degree.

So can I just say since every Galois extension is normal, all of the irreducible factors of $p$ in $F[X]$ are linear, i.e., $p$ splits over $F$. And given an irreducible $p\in L[X]$, $p$ has a root in $L$ if and only if $p$ admits a linear irreducible factor in $L[X]$, so all irreducible factors of $p(x) ∈ L[x]$ have the same degree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessarily the case that $p$ splits over $L$. But let $q(x)$ be
an irreducible factor of $p(x)$ over $L$. Applying an element of the Galois
group $\sigma\in G=\text{Gal}(L/F)$ to the coefficients of $q(x)$
gives a polynomial
$q^\sigma(x)$ which is also irreducible over $L$, also a factor of $p(x)$, and
of the same degree as $q(x)$. Either $q(x)=q^\sigma(x)$ or else $q(x)$ and
$q^\sigma(x)$ are coprime. By taking all the elements of $G$ one generates
a bunch of polynomials $q_1=q,\ldots,q_m$ say. Then $Q(x)=q_1(x)\cdots q_k(x)$
is a factor of $p(x)$, but is stable under $G$, so has coefficients in $F$.
As $p(x)$ is irreducible over $F$, $p(x)=Q(x)$. So the $q_i$ are the irreducible
factors of $p(x)$ over $L$, and they all have the same degree.

Comment: Do you mean $\{q_1(x)....q_k(x)\}$ is the orbit under the action by $G$ on $q(x)$? That will make sense

Comment: Why is $Q(x)$ a factor of $p(x)$?

Comment: @gen its because all $q_i$ are coprime, so their LCM should divide $p(x)$.