# Show that $f(x)$ factors in $K[x]$(whether or not $K$ is contained in the Galois closure $L$ of $f(x)$).

Tags: group-theory, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, galois-extensions

**Let $f(x)\in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over the field $F$. For any $K$ is any Galois extension of $F$, show that $f(x)$ factors in $K[x]$ see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86778/why-does-an-irreducible-polynomial-split-into-irreducible-factors-of-equal-degre) (whether or not $K$ is contained in the Galois closure $L$ of $f(x)$).**

I have proved:

> Suppose $f(x)\in F[X]$ is irreducible over a field $F$ with $\deg(f)=n$, and let $L$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$ with $\alpha$ a root of $f(x)$ in $L$. Let $K/F$ be a Galois extension, with $K\subset L$. Then why does $f(x)$ split into a product of $m$ irreducible polynomials of degree $d$ over $K$, with $m=[F(\alpha)\cap K:F]$ and $d=[K(\alpha):K]$?

The steps to prove this are : 1) Show that the factorisation of $f(x)$ over $K$ is the same as its factorisation over $L \cap K$.

2) Then show that the factors of $f(x)\in F[x]$ over $L \cap K$ correspond to the orbits of $H=Gal(L/L \cap K)$ on the roots of $f(x)$ and then proceed.

What's a good way to prove this, or at least proceed? Thank you for any insight.

***Edit:*** Let me clarify some of the doubts raised in the comment suppose $f$ is irreducible over $K$ then let it be. The question is not that $f(x)$ factors or not! The question is show that $f(x)$ factors in $K[x]$(whether or not $K$ is contained in the Galois closure $L$ of $f(x)$).

Observe my highlighted part: there is a possibility of $m$ being $1$ then $F(\alpha) \cap K=F$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$f(x)$ factors"?  If you mean that $f$ is not irreducible in $K[x]$ then this definitely is not true in general.

Comment: I find this question very confusing: I'm not even sure what the main question is. If it is what you wrote in the first three lines at the top, then the claim is false as noted in the above comment. Just take as an example $\;x^2-2\in\Bbb Q[x]\;$ and $\;K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)\;$ ...

Comment: $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ not over $K$.

Comment: @DonAntonio The question is what I wrote in the first 3 lines.

Comment: Hello , everyone now see my edited part. I hope that your confusion will get cleared

Comment: I already saw "this" and the claim still is false as you wrote it. In "this" there's given **the splitting field** of $\;f\;$ , which is never mentioned in your question! It is completely false that any irreducible polynomial over a field $\;F\;$ will split in *any* Galois extension of $\;F\;$ ...in fact, the example above (and many others exist) show that $\;f\;$ could not even have one miserable root on that Galois extension...

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, that is why I added the part "this" so that the wrong part can be corrected. Now can you help me?

Comment: @Gimgim I really don't understand what you **exactly** want: you say you already proved "this" so that is not a problem already... **then what**?? What is it you want? The first three lines? Those are *false*. Period.

Comment: Hi, if you have dummit foote then please see the section 14.4 exercise 4, if possible.